# Java web app debugging tools

Tags: java, debugging

I am wondering whether there exist any tool in Java, which would generate similar outputs on Exception like this tool on PHP:

http://examples.nette.org/ndebug/nette-exception.html

The Apache web stacktrace in comparison with this tool is a bit ugly and without the IDE's console not very useful.

Note the fact that the parts of the view are clickable and dynamic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is interpreted from source. Java is compiled into byte-code. The web server only has the byte-code, so I don't see how it could generate such a thing.

If you're debugging your webapp in an IDE, the stack trace should appear in the IDE console, and you should be able to click the stack trace and go to the corresponding line of code in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Not the same scenario, but very useful (and give better "output" than any logs could):

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/debug-your-java-code-with-ease-using-jpda/6139512

With JPDA you can debug your code just like a desktop application. You have variable inspection, stop/suspend/start, etc.